# insert back slash at the end of the url htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am doing a project on php.The dynamic url will be change to Search engine friendly url.I was creating htaccess  file for rewrite the url. i am not familiar with **.htaccess**. iam try ing to insert bakslash in to url.
 if the url not end with "**/**" or "**.html**" then add a backslash at the last.Please help to check the url end with "**/**" or "**.html**"

Now i am trying this code

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

this code only insert black slash into **http://www.example.com/hh** situation. but i will try to add backslash in any document root

eg

```
http://www.example.com/hh/yyy   - http://www.example.com/hh/yyy/
http://www.example.com/h        - http://www.example.com/h/
```

Comment: When you say [“backslash”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) you actually mean [forward slash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29), right?

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*[^/]+)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this  only applicable for **http: //www.example.com/hdd** case it not redirect the  **http: //www.example.com/hdd/hh** .